# Angular JS manipulating dom by element from link function

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

we know that we can access dom from directive by element because element is injected in link function.

### see the approach

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive('busyBox',function(){
     return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.on('click', function(){
            if(attrs.id=='btnadd')
            {

              var divElement = angular.element(document.body.querySelector('.parent')).append('<div class="child">Some text</div>');
        //     console.log(divElement);
             //  element.parent().find('.parent').append('<div>Some text</div>')
                //element.closest('.parent').append('<div class="child">child</div>')
              //angular.element(document).find('.parent').append('<div class="child">child</div>');
            }
            else if(attrs.id=='btnDel')
            {
            angular.element(document.body.querySelector('.child')).remove();
           //    m.removeChild(m.firstChild);
            }
          }); 

        }
        }
})
```

the above code is working but if i do not use `angular.element()` instead if i use `element(document.body.querySelector('.parent'))` the code is not working.

the element is injected in link function `link: function(scope, element, attrs)`
when element is there in directive then why should i use `angular.element()` ?

please tell me how could i use element from directive to access dom instead of `angular.element()`.

thanks

Comment: The `element` exposed to the postLink function is a **jqLite** class object which is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows AngularJS to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. **jqLite** implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal of having a very small footprint. The `find()`  method is limited to lookups by tag name. For more information, see [AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > please tell me how could i use element from directive to access dom instead of angular.element()

If you want to use the `element` object that is passed into the link function of the directive to manipulate the DOM, you have to use [various methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) that the element object exposes, like `find`.

Do not use it like this:

```
element(document.body.querySelector('.parent'))
```

Instead you can do:

```
// works only if you are using jQuery
element.find('.parent');
// for JQLite, the find method is limited to lookup by tag name:
element.find('div');
```

Note that as mentioned in the answer from @georgeawg, that you might be using JQLite or JQuery ... where the JQLite functionality is not as full featured as JQuery.

Comment: Can't we use element. Closest function instead of find to get the div?

Answer (score 1):

The `element` exposed to the postLink function is a **jqLite** class object which is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows AngularJS to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. **jqLite** implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal of having a very small footprint.

The `find()`  method is limited to lookups by tag name. If you want the `find()` method to work with class selectors, load jQuery before the `angular.js` file.

> If jQuery is available, `angular.element` is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, `angular.element` delegates to AngularJS's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.
>
> To use jQuery, simply ensure it is loaded before the `angular.js` file. You can also use the `ngJq` directive to specify that jqlite should be used over jQuery, or to use a specific version of jQuery if multiple versions exist on the page.
>
> [— AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

---

---

> Can't we use element. `closest` function instead of `find` to get the div?

The [jQuery closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function is not part of [AngularJS jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). To use the `closest` function with the `element` value exposed to the directive postLink function, load the jQuery library before loading the AngularJS library.

For the list of jqLite functions, see [AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)